# VICIDial IP based configuratoin.. No Outgoing calls

Tags: performance, asterisk, vici

I have configured my carrier settings as below,

```
 [100]
    disallow=all
    allow=ulaw
    allow=g729
    type=friend
    dtmfmode=rfc2833
    qualify=yes
    insecure=invite,port
    nat=force_rport,comedia
    fromuser=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    canreinvite=no
    port=5060

Global Stirng :     VoiPHola=SIP/100

    Dial Entry Plan

    exten => _1.,1,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log)
    exten => _1.,2,Dial(${100}/3000#${EXTEN:1},,tTo)
    exten => _1.,3,Hangup
```

When I logged in as Agent, there is no calls outgoing and after sometime the Dial Timeout error comes at agent screen... 
    What is causing the issue?

Comment: Nobody will do debug for you. What exactly you have done to debug this question?

Answer (score 0):

Your global string variable name is `VoiPHola`, but your dial variable is `${100}`, these have to match. Use `${VoiPHola}` and they match.

Note that all the string variable does is get replace with the right side of the equal sign in the dial plan entry when it runs. Thus you COULD just put `SIP/100` in `Dial(SIP/100/3000#${EXTEN:1},,tTo)` instead for the same effect.

But then you wouldn't be using the variable and if you changed this variable definition it would have zero effect anywhere. In theory you can use this variable in multiple carrier configurations (such as a failover dialplan?). Global Strings not really necessary.

MOST importantly (as pointed out by arheops), this is not really the appropriate venue for your question. Vicidial.com has a forum for this where lots of Vicidial Pros and Cons (oops: amateurs) will answer questions like this for you and help you get going.